# Horizontal scrollbar show when screen is large

Tags: html, css

I am practicing my layout but I'm facing a problem with my layout. I'm a beginner with flex and grid CSS. As you can see in the picture the horizontal scrollbar shows when the screen width is 1440 or above. I don't want to show that. I also tried the overflow-x: hidden but it always shows. How can I fix that? Thanks so much!

[image: SS]

This is my code:

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@100;300;400;500;600;800&display=swap");

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: "Inter", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  color: #262626;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #262626;
}

ul,
li,
ol {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.btn {
  width: 105px;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 36px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 36px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border: none;
}

.btn-none {
  color: #037cff;
  background: #fff;
}

.btn-primary {
  color: #fff;
  background: #037cff;
}

.btn-secondary {
  color: #037cff;
  background: #e6f2ff;
}

.section-title {
  font-size: 32px;
}

.main-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

.main-container .nav-section {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 60px;
  padding: 20px 0;
}

.main-container .nav-section .logo-container h2 {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #007cff;
  width: 128px;
  margin: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.main-container .nav-section ul.menu-container {
  display: flex;
}

.main-container .nav-section ul li {
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.main-container .nav-section ul li a {
  font-size: 14px;
}

.main-container .nav-section .btn-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.main-container .hero-container {
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  height: calc(100vh - 80px);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  padding-top: 100px;
  column-gap: 12px;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.main-container .hero-container .hero-text-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  max-width: 580px;
}

.main-container .hero-container .hero-text-container h1 {
  font-size: 48px;
  font-weight: 800;
  margin: 0;
}

.main-container .hero-container .hero-text-container h1 span {
  color: #007cff;
}

.main-container .hero-container .hero-text-container p:last-child {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.main-container .hero-container .hero-image-container img {
  max-width: 580px;
  max-height: 560px;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  margin-top: 25px;
}

.main-container .hero-container button {
  width: 300px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  height: 55px;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Gadget Store</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="main-container">
      <!-- Nav Section -->
      <nav class="nav-section">
        <div class="logo-container">
          <h2>Gadget <span>Zone</span></h2>
        </div>
        <ul class="menu-container">
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Reviews</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Deals</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Gears</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Gaming</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Entertainment</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="btn-container">
          <button class="btn btn-none">Sign In</button>
          <button class="btn btn-primary btn-rad">Login</button>
        </div>
      </nav>

      <!-- Hero Section -->
      <section class="hero-container">
        <div class="hero-text-container">
          <h1>
            Best way to <br />
            find your <span>gadget</span> needs.
          </h1>
          <p>
            Find the latest technology news and expert tech product reviews.
            <br />
            Learn about the latest gadgets and consumer tech products for
            entertainment, gaming, lifestyle and more.
          </p>
          <p>All gadgets are priced to be customer-friendly.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="hero-image-container">
          <img src="https://svgshare.com/i/b9d.svg" alt="Hero" />
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-secondary">Learn more</button>
      </section>

      <!-- Reviews Section -->
      <section class="reviews-section">
        <h1 class="section-title">Latest Reviews</h1>
      </section>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hiding overflow isn't usually a solution--it just masks problems. The best approach in cases like this is often to start removing widths from things. You're forcing some that don't help.

Here, set the `left` value of your navbar so it's in frame. You may need to add padding to move the logo and button over.

Then, remove the width rule from the main container element.

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@100;300;400;500;600;800&display=swap");

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: "Inter", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  color: #262626;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #262626;
}

ul,
li,
ol {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.btn {
  width: 105px;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 36px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 36px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border: none;
}

.btn-none {
  color: #037cff;
  background: #fff;
}

.btn-primary {
  color: #fff;
  background: #037cff;
}

.btn-secondary {
  color: #037cff;
  background: #e6f2ff;
}

.section-title {
  font-size: 32px;
}

.main-container {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

.main-container .nav-section {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0; /* <----------------------------------------- HERE */
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 60px;
  padding: 20px 0;
}

.main-container .nav-section .logo-container h2 {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #007cff;
  width: 128px;
  margin: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.main-container .nav-section ul.menu-container {
  display: flex;
}

.main-container .nav-section ul li {
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.main-container .nav-section ul li a {
  font-size: 14px;
}

.main-container .nav-section .btn-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.main-container .hero-container {
  display: grid;
  height: calc(100vh - 80px);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  padding-top: 100px;
  column-gap: 12px;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.main-container .hero-container .hero-text-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  max-width: 580px;
}

.main-container .hero-container .hero-text-container h1 {
  font-size: 48px;
  font-weight: 800;
  margin: 0;
}

.main-container .hero-container .hero-text-container h1 span {
  color: #007cff;
}

.main-container .hero-container .hero-text-container p:last-child {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.main-container .hero-container .hero-image-container img {
  max-width: 580px;
  max-height: 560px;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  margin-top: 25px;
}

.main-container .hero-container button {
  width: 300px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  height: 55px;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
  <!-- Nav Section -->
  <nav class="nav-section">
    <div class="logo-container">
      <h2>Gadget <span>Zone</span></h2>
    </div>
    <ul class="menu-container">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Reviews</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Deals</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Gears</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Gaming</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Entertainment</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="btn-container">
      <button class="btn btn-none">Sign In</button>
      <button class="btn btn-primary btn-rad">Login</button>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <!-- Hero Section -->
  <section class="hero-container">
    <div class="hero-text-container">
      <h1>
        Best way to <br />
        find your <span>gadget</span> needs.
      </h1>
      <p>
        Find the latest technology news and expert tech product reviews.
        <br />
        Learn about the latest gadgets and consumer tech products for
        entertainment, gaming, lifestyle and more.
      </p>
      <p>All gadgets are priced to be customer-friendly.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="hero-image-container">
      <img src="https://svgshare.com/i/b9d.svg" alt="Hero" />
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-secondary">Learn more</button>
  </section>

  <!-- Reviews Section -->
  <section class="reviews-section">
    <h1 class="section-title">Latest Reviews</h1>
  </section>
</div>
```